# I am unable to use Nuget Nlua to read .lua file in C#

Tags: c#, lua, nlua

Using visual studio with class application I added the NLua via NuGet.
I want to read in and .lua file (BTW, of there is a better way do let me know)
My code is this:

```
...
using NLua;
...
using (Lua lua = new Lua())...
```

But when I run it I get an exception on the above line:

*System.BadImageFormatException
HResult=0x8007000B
Message=An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
Source=KeraLua
StackTrace:
at KeraLua.NativeMethods.luaL_newstate()
at NLua.Lua..ctor()*

What am I doing wrong? I tried to search the internet and came up with solutions that it is since I am running a 64bit app while the one I am trying to load (NLUA) in 32bit.
Is that it?

THANK YOU

Comment: Are your ```lua.DoString...``` works correctly? if no is LuaDist  had installed ( or somethings like that ) in your machine before??

Comment: I cannot define a new Lua() object at all therefore I cant use lua.DoString.
I did not install LusDist, as far as I know

Comment: what about LuaDist installation ( or other versions of lua in windows )  in your system?

Comment: I have a game DCS which is using LUA language. This is why I want to use lua. to read its files

Comment: how can i check if i have this and fix this?

Comment: Have you try to change ```Platform target ``` from ```x64``` to "Any Cpu" ? (if the answer is  no you can find it in your project properties-> build  section)

Comment: i have, it was set to "Any CPU", I tried both x86 and 64 with the same result and put it back to "Any CPU"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219078/discussion-between-dandan-and-ali-bigdeli).

Comment: What versions of `Nlua` and `KeraLua` are you using?

Comment: I downloaded in via visual studio "Add Nuget" panel.
It's the latest I believe.
Nlua 1.5.0 KeraLue 1.2.4

Comment: I tried on another PC, without the game code and I get the same error.
I don't know if it is related but I try to use Lua from within a class library, being invoked from my test console app